# Newton's method on a surface

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, algorithms, integro-differential-equations

I am trying to use Newton's method to find the stationary solutions of the integro-differential equation of the form $$\frac{\partial u(r,t)}{\partial t} = -u(r,t) + \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}w(r - r')f(u(r',t))\mathrm{d}r' \quad\quad r\in\mathbb{R}^{2}. $$ I began by implementing Newton's method for the 1D version of the above, where $u(r)$ is discretized on the domain to give a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Newtons method then amounts to solving at each iteration the system of equations $$ Jx = -F,$$ where $J$ is the Jacobian, $J\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the current iterate, and $F\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the discretized right-hand side of the first equation.  I implemented this just fine in this 1D case, using GMRES to solve the system of equations at each step.

I must now attempt to do the same procedure for the 2D case, where $r\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and therefore $u(r)$ is now a discretized surface function - i.e. an $n\times n$ matrix. But I don't know how to proceed. It seems to me that at each iteration of Newton, I would need to solve something like $$ Jx = -F\quad\quad x,F\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}.$$ Does this mean that I should essentially solve the above system one row or one column at a time perhaps?

I'm not quite sure if I've made my situation clear. To give some intuition, the 2D stationary states I'm looking for will look like this: [image]

So the above surface function is discretized to give a matrix $u\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. I can't seem to find any help online about how to do Newton's method on a surface like this! Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For the 2D case the $J$ matrix would be from $\mathbb R^{n^2 \times n^2}$ (you need to treat $x, F$ as vectors from $\mathbb R^{n^2}$), dense, since you're solving an integral equation. Afaik, that cannot be solved row by row or column by column.

Comment: Is there a typo in your equation? Looks like an ODE to me. Also why are you using Newton's method for a linear problem?

Comment: You're right there is a typo - there should be a $t$ parameter: it should be like $u(r,t)$.

Comment: Your integral does not depend on $u$. That makes it effectively just a right-hand side

Comment: Christ, I've made so many typos! It does depend on $u$. Let me amend it.

Comment: Ah, makes sense now.

Comment: Can you please provide also the $f(u)$ function? Is it simple?

Comment: Yes, its just $1/(1 + \mathrm{exp}(\mu(u(r,t)-h))$, $\mu$ and $h$ are just some parameters

Comment: For context, this is a neural field  model. $f$ is the neuron firing function, $w$ describes the connectivity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26484/discussion-between-uranix-and-o-smith).